# Crash when opening a file with non-ascii characters - how to diagnose?

Tags: osx, crash, utf-8

Running MacOSX GUI emacs installed via homebrew.

Whenever I open a regular text file that contains non-ASCII characters, Emacs immediately crashes. These files have no header lines specifying encoding or other settings.

Works fine in terminal-mode emacs.

I'd like to understand the cause of the crash, not just make it go away. Emacs leaves no core file or other debris.

Comment: It might be helpful to start by minimizing the size of the file that causes the crash. If you delete the second half, does Emacs still crash? This can help figure out what's going on (e.g., "oh, it's only when Emacs has bidirectional characters next to an non-breaking space"). You can also see if this is related to a specific mode -- for example, if the file is `whatever.org`, try renaming it to `whatever.txt` and seeing if it's org-mode that's crashing. You can then run `M-x report-emacs-bug` to tell the developers about it.

Comment: Is the result the same if the file is opened in `fundamental-mode`?

Comment: Technically, you could run it in `gdb`. Even without debug symbols it's typically enough info to make a good guess as to what might have happened. Also, what if Homebrew actually has debug info for Emacs binaries?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might be bumping into [Emacs bug #21428](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=21428): **24.5; Crash of emacs on OS X, installed via homebrew cask**.

It's still being investigated.  If you follow the bug thread perhaps you can contribute to helping understand it.